# WebRTC: Switch camera

Tags: webrtc

I want to be able to switch the camera while in the middle of a conversation with WebRTC, without **renegotiating** the call.

Suppose we have 2 "mediaSources" objects using the `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` method:

```
{
    id: "id_source_1" | "id_source_2",
    facing: "user" | "environment",
    kind: "kind_1" | "kind_2",
    label: "label_1" | "label_2"
 }
```

We start the call with "source_1" (facing the "user"), and we want the user to be able to switch to "source_2" (facing the "environment").

In my current code when the user clicks the "switch camera" button the following is executed: (`callingSession` is the current WebRTC session)

```
var mediaParams = {
       audio: true,
       video: { deviceId : source_2.id},
       options: {
           muted: true,
           mirror: true
       },
       elemId: 'localVideo'
};

callingSession.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function (error, stream) {
if (error) {
   console.error('error getting user media');
} else {
          var oldVideoTracks = callingSession.localStream.getVideoTracks();      
          var newVideoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

          if (oldVideoTracks.length > 0 && newVideoTracks.length > 0) {
               callingSession.localStream.removeTrack(oldVideoTracks[0]);
               callingSession.localStream.addTrack(newVideoTracks[0]);
          } 
       }
 });
```

As you can see the `mediaParams` constraints is now set to the "source_2", we pass this `mediaParams` with new constraints to the `getUserMedia` method. Then we get the video tracks from both the old and the new stream.

The main problem in this code, is that the old stream is still exactly the same as the new stream, even with the new constraints passed to the `getUserMedia` method, so obviously the same video tracks, and of course nothing happens, and the camera is not switched !!!

Am I doing something wrong in this code ? is there any way to switch the camera without without **renegotiating** the call in WebRTC ? what about the experimental method `applyConstraint()` I am not able to see it in chrome ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
My WebRTC app is an ionic app with crosswalk => the webview is chrome

Comment: I would isolate and make sure you can view two cameras at the same time locally first (many phones disallow using front and back camera at the same time for instance) before messing with peer connection. Also, use `video: {deviceId: {exact: source_2.id}}` to force the constraint. Lastly, `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` has been superseded by `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`, so try that. If all that works, try removing the stream from the peer connection before messing with it, and re-add it after.

Comment: @jib With the current implementation I am able to switch the sources locally (works also in mobile devices). I am not able to switch the streams sent to the peer.

Comment: I'm no expert on Chrome (this isn't a problem in Firefox which supports `replaceTrack`), but in Chrome I think you may still have to [renegotiate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504214/how-to-addtrack-in-mediastream-in-webrtc/35515536#35515536), which you could do over a data channel, so it'd be near seamless.

Comment: @jib thanks for the very useful link. I am trying to renegotiate using the data channel. I can with the current peerConnection create an offer, then set the local description. still when i create the data channel `peerConnection.createDataChannel` its state is never open. Is there any extra steps to do to open the data channel ?

Comment: `pc.createDataChannel` is like `pc.addStream`, in that you call it *before* creating the offer. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/k6wddxa2/).

Answer (score 8):

At the time of writing this post, the WebRTC [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/) is very promising but still the implementation of this specification varies from browser to another. Currently the Chrome implementation is still old. Nevertheless thanks to jib comments and to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504214/how-to-addtrack-in-mediastream-in-webrtc/35515536#35515536) and also more understanding of the [SDP (Session Description Protocol)](https://webrtchacks.com/update-anatomy-webrtc-sdp-anton-roman/) I can now switch the camera using Chrome.

First the constraints to my `getUserMedia` method were wrong, here is how I managed to pass the right constraints :

```
var mediaParams = {
            // the other constraints
            video: {mandatory: {sourceId: source_2.id}}
            // ...
        };
```

After calling `getUserMedia` with the `mediaParams` argument we need to remove the current stream from the peer connection then add the new one like this :

```
peerConnection.removeStream(peerConnection.getLocalStreams()[0]);
peerConnection.addLocalStream(stream);
```

Those two lines of code will trigger the `onnegotiationneeded` on the `peerConnection` object, means peer 1 must tell peer 2 he changed the stream so he needs a new description. Thats why we need to create an offer, set the new description and send this new description to the peer :

```
peerConnection.createOffer()
.then(function (offer) {
      peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
})
.then(function () {
      send(JSON.stringify({ "sdp": peerConnection.localDescription }));
});
```

At this point its up to you how you want to `send` the SDP. (In my use case I had to send them using WebSockets.)

Once the other peer receives the new SDP he must set it in his own peer connection :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(answer).sdp;
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(obj));
```

I hope this will help someone someday.

Comment: Thanks man!
I wasted my 12hrs on this and your answer made my day. But there is a problem I am facing when switching camera faces. My video call gets dropped if I toggle camera facing 3-4 times.
The problem is in oniceconnectionstatechanged.

Comment: @hamzox  i dont recall the exact details, but for some reason the `onnegotiationneeded` is triggered twice. i just created a boolean, i switch the state of the boolean in the `onnegotiationneeded` callback, and if the boolean is `true` then i execute the `peerConnection.createOffer`, this ensure that the `createOffer` is executed 1 out of 2. its a hack indeed, but i didnt want to waste more time on this ;) hope this helps

Comment: Hi @dafriskymonkey with ur help the camera is switching but the stream changing part isnt happening. Can you help me with more elaborate code for peer connection please. Been stuck with this for a very long time

Answer (score 7):

In order to replace the current camera, without losing the candidate process you must use the following example code, obviously replacing your own variables:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream){
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        var sender = peerConnCallee.getSenders().find(function(s) {
          return s.track.kind == track.kind;
        });
        sender.replaceTrack(track);
    });
})
.catch(function(e) { });
```

You can see it working in the next site:
[Can Peek](https://www.canpeek.com)

Comment: This comment was really helpful to me. Here's the link for MDN documentation of it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to switch camera and update the video track *for both remote peer connection and your local video stream* (e.g. you're show the local video to the user himself), here is a more comprehensive solution. It uses TypeScript, but can be easily converted into plain JS if needed.
The solution seems long, but it's well structured and split into multiple re-usable functions.

```js
// assuming RTCPeerConnection is initialized in variable `peerConnection`,
// and local MediaStream is stored in variable `localStream` 
// (you can also extract local stream from the video element's "srcObject")

enum CameraFacingMode {
    FRONT = 'user',
    BACK = 'environment'
};

let facingMode: CameraFacingMode.FRONT; // assuming this was the initial value
 
async function toggleFacingMode() {
    facingMode = facingMode === CameraFacingMode.FRONT ? CameraFacingMode.BACK : CameraFacingMode.FRONT;
    return switchCameraFacingMode(localStream, peerConnection, facingMode);
}


/**
 * Switch to the new facingMode without stopping the existing stream and hopefully without re-negotiating RTC connection
 */
async function switchCameraFacingMode(localStream: MediaStream, peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, facingMode: CameraFacingMode) {
    const oldVideoTrack = localStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const oldVideoConstraints = oldVideoTrack.getConstraints();
    const newConstraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            ...oldVideoConstraints,
            facingMode
        }
    };

    // must stop the old video track before creating a new stream, 
    // otherwise some devices throw an error because we're trying
    // to access 2 cameras at the same time
    oldVideoTrack.stop();

    const bufferStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(newConstraints);
    const newVideoTrack = bufferStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

    await replaceVideoTrackInPeerConnection(peerConnection, newVideoTrack);

    replaceVideoTrackInLocalStream(localStream, newVideoTrack);
}

function replaceVideoTrackInLocalStream(localStream: MediaStream, track: MediaStreamTrack): void {
    const oldVideoTrack = localStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

    localStream.removeTrack(oldVideoTrack);
    localStream.addTrack(track);
}

function replaceVideoTrackInPeerConnection(connection: RTCPeerConnection, track: MediaStreamTrack): Promise<void> {
    const sender = connection.getSenders().find(
        s => s.track.kind === track.kind
    );

    return sender?.replaceTrack(track);
}
```

Special attention to the functions `replaceVideoTrackInLocalStream` and `replaceVideoTrackInPeerConnection` as they show how to replace video track in remote connection as well as local video stream.

Answer (score 1):

replaceTrack API was defined just for this.

Eventually chrome will support the RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack method (http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcrtpsender-interface), which can be used to replace a track without renegotiation. You can track the development of that feature in Chrome here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5347809238712320

It's already available to some extent in the native API. But it's currently under development, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I dont know how to use `replaceTrack ` since the `stream` in the `getUserMedia` is the exact same as the `callingSession.localStream`

Answer (score 0):

**No need to re-negotiate when we can replaceTrack**

Following worked for me for multiple peerConnections.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack

'''

```
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: {
      deviceId: {
        exact: window.selectedCamera
      }
    }
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    PCs.forEach(function(pc) {
      var sender = pc.getSenders().find(function(s) {
        return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
      });
      console.log('found sender:', sender);
      sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Error happens:', err);
  });
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's only me but if someone else cannot call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` because your camera is busy `(notReadableError: Could not start video source)`, try adding this before calling `getUserMedia()`

```
for(let p in pc){
    let pName = pc[p];
    pc[pName] && pc[pName].getSenders().forEach(s => s.track && s.track.stop());
}
myStream.getTracks().length ? myStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()) : '';
```

It might be busy by the remote peers as well as your local stream.