# Webrtc renegotiation , Firefox to Chrome , Vice Versa , Not updating streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I have already made the Peer Connection Successfully , But I am not able to make proper renegotiation b/w Chrome <-> Firefox

---

**I have followed the steps for renegotiation ( While change camera / Video to screen share ),**

1. Update the streams / tracks (add/remove) (Changer)
2. That hits onnegotiationneeded (Changer)
3. Create Offer (Changer)
4. Set Local Desc (Changer)
5. Send it to another peer connection (Changer)
6. Set Remote Desc (Receiver)
7. Create Answer (Receiver)
8. Set Local Desc (Receiver)
9. Set Remote Desc (Changer)

---

**Things works all great** , While it is Chrome -> Chrome , Safari , Opera or Firefox -> Firefox

**But not working when** it comes to Firefox -> Chrome , Safari , Opera or Chrome -> Firefox

---

ICE candidates are also need to be updated on renegotiation ?

I am bit confused about the renegotiation flow , as it is not written any where , How it should be executed.

---

> Note : Replace Track is working great but only issue with that is not
>   supported in older version of the browser , That's Why I am using
>   Renegotiation method.
>
> Using all the latest version browser till date.

Comment: do you have a chrome://webrtc-internals dump? The full trace is much easier to interpret (see https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/) as it shows all events happening.

Comment: @PhilippHancke , Yes I do have , https://gist.github.com/vivekdoshi2/ed64056b9a0fc8680ebf6426ab325367

Comment: @PhilippHancke , Found anything ?

Comment: When imported on http://fippo.github.io/webrtc-dump-importer/ you can see that 
the firefox offer in the second setRemoteDescription call contains more than two m= lines. This is unified plan and Chrome can not parse that (prior to M68 where this can be configured with the sdpSemantics flag).

Comment: @PhilippHancke , I was thinking that , it might be the issue , But it os working for the first time , then how is that working ? and also what's the solution for this ?

Comment: https://github.com/jitsi/sdp-interop might be a solution. Not an easy one though.

Comment: @PhilippHancke, Thanks for making sure the issue as I was not 100% sure that only this can cause the problem , let me try sdp-interop , let's see what happens. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @PhilippHancke , Do you know how to use that package on browser side ? I have tried to build it with gulp browerify but not getting Interop object.

Comment: As @PhilippHancke has correctly mentioned the problem is the the SDP between Firefox and Chrome are currently incompatible in cases where there is **more than one track of the same type (i.e. two video streams)**.

So your problem has likely nothing to do with renegotiation per se, but with the fact that you end up with multiple tracks of the same type after it.

Was it your intention to end up with multiple tracks of the same type?

Comment: I just want to replace video track , with the screen share means another video track @SaeedJahed

Comment: I know the code is ugly, but in Firefox you can try using replaceTrack, which would avoid needing to renegotiate. But that still won't solve having to renegotiate on Chrome side. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack

Comment: Another ugly solution is to re-establish your peer connection each time, instead of renegotiation. That will get around the Chrome vs Firefox interop issues if you're just replacing tracks.

Comment: @SaeedJahed , I have created whole demo with that but what will happen , If started the call with audio only and then want to share the screen , in that case I need to renegotiate , right ?